# Simple identity in Coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I am probably missing something fundamental.

I can prove the following "identity":

```
Theorem identity_simple : forall a : Prop, a -> a.
```

With `intro. intro. assumption.`.

However, I can't seem to prove:

```
Theorem identity : forall a : Prop, a.
```

Of course I can do `intro`, but that leaves me with:

```
a : Prop
_________(1/1)
a
```

With which I do not know what to do.
The first form seems redundant, to state that for all `a`, `a` implies `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
forall a : Prop, a -> a.
```

reads as "given the proof of some proposition `a` we can construct a proof of the same proposition". Which is true, since we can just return the original proof.

Let's check it with Coq:

```
Print identity_simple.
(* 
output:

identity_simple = fun (a : Prop) (H : a) => H
     : forall a : Prop, a -> a
*)
```

the proof term `fun (a : Prop) (H : a) => H` expresses exactly the described behavior.

> The first form seems redundant, to state that for all `a`, `a` implies `a`.

You are right in some sense -- it *is* pretty obvious. You can think of it as a test -- if you *cannot* prove it then there must be something wrong with the logic.

---

```
forall a : Prop, a.
```

reads as "we can construct a proof of *any* proposition". Which is not true, since for example, you cannot construct the proof of `False` (in the empty context). And that would be a disaster -- we wouldn't want to use a logic in which *everything* is provable.

Comment: How does this relate to transition from implication to universal quantification if the quantified variable doesn't occur in the consequent? For example, if I wanted to do something along the lines of `Theorem identity : forall x : Prop, forall y : x, y.` which Coq doesn't like.

Comment: You can translate it as `x` is some proposition, `y` is its proof *term*, and you want to construct something of *type* `y`. But it won't typecheck since `y` is a term and not a type. Does that explanation make sense?

Comment: Is there a way to translate universal quantification to implication and backwards in this case then? Or is this is best attempt which happens to not typecheck even tho if we assumed congruence and substitution of x / Prop in `forall y : x` we'd get `forall y : Prop` which would already be ok for Coq... I am a bit confused.

Comment: (1) One direction is easy: in Coq, `->` is just notation for `forall`: `Notation "A -> B" := (forall (_ : A), B) : type_scope.` (it's defined in [Coq.Init.Logic](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Logic.html)). (2) The reverse is not always possible (if `B` depends on `x` we can't do it). (3) Could you state the problem on your hands *informally*? Maybe we could figure something out...

Comment: This is actually the problem itself - I want the identity in both the implies form `a -> a` kind of thing and in the `forall` form :). So I guess `forall a : Prop, a -> a` would be `forall a : Prop, (forall (x : a), a)`... oh, now it all makes sense... I think I need a cup of coffee, I've had an epiphany, thanks a lot, you've just saved me a lot of headaches :).